# Loading wrong assemblies on non-dev machines?

Tags: dll, assemblies, reference, gac

I think I'm falling into a common category of, "It works perfectly in my dev environment, but anywhere else I get strange results," and for all my efforts I'm only more confused.

I have 2 applications. One of them is .NET 4 C# app, and the other is (I think) .NET 3.5 VB.  The C# app creates a DLL, that for the time being, I have a version of this DLL compiled with 3.5 so that I can use it in my VB app.  I have the source to the VB app, but not the C# app.  I've never compiled the C# app on my machine.

Within this DLL, it references a C-based library. (I feel this is the problem.)

In my dev environment, I can use this DLL without any issue in my VB app.  However, when I try this setup on another machine, it acts as though the bits relating to that embedded C-based DLL are not the most recent version.

- gacutil confirms that the C# DLL isn't coming from the GAC
- FUSLOGVW confirms that the fully qualified name of the C# DLL being referenced is the same in both the dev/non-dev environments

  Within my VB app, and inside my app.config, I explicitly declare the C# DLL name, token and version.

  Within my VB app, on my reference of this DLL, I have "Copy Local" and "Specific Version" set to False

  Even with copying my C-based DLL and C# DLL to a target machine, the seemingly bad reference still occurs.

  Even loading the apps anew on a fresh system... the problem presents itself.

It's not that I get any errors.  The VB app still runs fine. The VB app is instantiating and using that C# DLL (which within it has the C DLL), and I can see that the inconsistencies from the VB app appear to be issues with the C DLL.  I've never had the source code to the C# app on my machine, and so I haven't any idea why it works well on my own, but not anywhere else.

I feel I've reached the end of what little I know about this, and I don't see anywhere else to go. I do feel that I should be able to re-create a working environment on other machines, though.

What else can I look in to?

**Edit**

I thought I may add some more specific information in the hopes that it leads to a solution.  For the time being, I've updated the VB code to work with the differing values.

This picture represents the values returned from one of the C-DLL methods on my machine.
[image]

Everything looks as it should.  I then take my DLLs and executable to fresh machine, run it, and these same items appear as:

[image]

I've checked the GAC several times. I've stared blankly at the loaded assembly logs for several hours only to take note that the same (correct) DLLs are being loaded in both environments. I've ensured the same various MS updates are installed on both machines. I've removed all 3rd party DLLs from both environments, that are used in the project, and reloaded them to both.

At this point, I have no clue what is causing this to happen.  There's no errors. It works just as happily on everyone's machine as it does my own, but I am thoroughly convinced (probably to own inability to see the actual problem) that my dev machine creates/has "something" I'm failing to move over, change the reference, etc.  I just currently feel as though I've exhausted my limited knowledge on the matter.

Oh, one last thing, the DLLs were provided to me from a VS2010 environment.  I'll have 2010 tomorrow, and hope to use the normal .NET 4 DLL instead of the 3.5 I requested.  This currently is my last hope for fixing this issue short of me changing the VB code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if I have missed something, but have you considered, that it might be just formatting settings, not different results?
From your example, I can only see the same results displayed in two different formattings (one with two fixed decimal places, and the other showing only relevant numbers).
If you check in your code if the top value == 2.0 it should be true on all computers, and if so - the DLL returns the same values on all computers, and they are just displayed differently (maybe computer locale settings differ?)